# Как подключить workbench к mysql на openshift?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, openshift

Доброго времени суток! В общем такая задача: необходимо подключить workbench к mysql серверу, развернутому на openshift. Если ip и port из вкладки applications -> services в openshift скопировать в подключение программы, то программа подключиться не может. Спасибо большое!

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, необходимо создать route для mysql сервера. Создал, но толку ноль, на этом адресе вообще ничего нет, даже пинг теряет всё(